# What's the appropriate verb for "Raising a pet and taking care of it"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've always been searching for a good meaningful VERB for that

i can't find, wherever i go .... is there any word that can help me?

it's not like "Raising a Dog"
even if it's informal !
HELP PLEASE. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! 1) Requests for words or phrases must include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. 2) I would think that "raise" covers the meaning you want. Please edit to show what you take "raise" to mean, and what different meaning you're looking for.

Comment: You can raise a pet without taking care of it?

Comment: @YosefBaskin If they are half-breed wolves or feral, then yes. That said, maybe "watching it grow up" would be more apt.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_The OP is talking about pets. I think your comment went out of range!

Comment: @AndyBonner i would say :
i had raised this bird for a long time.
as simple as it is .... i just want some accurate established synonyms

Comment: Well, if it's a rabbit it's "Hare raising".

Comment: This question needs  a lot more revision...but as an old country kid, I think we used to call it "hand rearing" when the animal is orphaned. I will try to salvage this Q tomorrow...

Comment: What breed of bird? In what country? It is possible  that the OP's usage of English is not sufficient to describe the circumstances. r.e. "pet"

Comment: Please note that sharing extra information in the comments isn't the same as editing the question; comments are not always permanent. To re-open this question, it needs to be edited to include a sample sentence, and I would say needs to better explain the meaning that is wanted. Are you looking for a word that means "provide care for" but also specifically includes "while the pet is very young"? Are you looking more for words about providing for needs, or about training? By the way, you might find the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)... um, helpful.

Comment: If you are looking for a word that is specifically for taking care of the pet until it reaches maturity, then you need to explain why *raising* itself is not inadequate. Or, are you looking for word for taking care of a pet throughout the pet's life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rear**

> to bring to maturity or self-sufficiency usually through nurturing care

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rear

FWIW I think raise is fine also.

Comment: This is the most obvious answer that was for some reason escaping the other users here.  +1

Comment: This does not distinguish between a pet and a child.

Comment: @Xanne This is inclusive, not exclusive.

Comment: Then does the pet go out into the wild wild world as would a child?  Note that pets are not cattle.

Comment: In fact I think this is answer is incorrect. Certainly nurturing is involved, but well beyond maturity.

Comment: You can rear cattle and you can rear a child. Different uses. But whatever, I thought raise was fine but the OP wanted something else.